# Mapping from an OWL ontology to Neo4j graph database

Tags: neo4j

I am working with OWL and I have created a very big ontology. I use the OWL API developed at the University of Manchester (http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/).
The problem is that, only with the OWL API, the ontology is loaded in memory. There are two valuable solutions that transfer the data from the ontology in a database and then give the possibility to query the ontology from the database without the need to load it in memory. These solutions are OWLDB, which uses relational databases, and HypergraphDB.
My question is the following: is there already a solution implemented to map an OWL ontology (developed with the OWL API) to a Neo4j graph database? If not, is there any chance to have such a mapping in the future? It would be really helpful.

Thank you.
Oana

Answer (score 0):

There is now a page on neo4j.org with more info on RDF, LinkedData and Neo4j, see http://www.neo4j.org/develop/linked_data

Answer (score 0):

If you look here http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/08/and-now-for-something-completely.html you get an idea of how it can be implemented using just the OWLAPI to build the Neo4j graph manually.